# How can I loop through a Firestore database to find the first value != nil?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, uikit

I am currently using Google Firestore to host a database, allowing users to add in a series of products. Whenever a user adds their first product, this is added fine. However, once the user adds a second product, the initial product data is always overwritten as my method which sends the data to the Database is hardcoded as "product1". I am trying to create a function which reads all of the fields in my database beginning with "product" to try and find the first "product" + "integer" which isn't currently in the database, and to use this name and add the data. I am currently trying to increment the value afterward the "product" name e.g. ("product1", "product2" etc.) and then once it finds a "product(Int)" which is equal to nil (indicating that the field is empty/doesn't exist yet), then the data can be added using this "product(Int)" value. In the example image below, the database currently has "product1" populated with data, so when a user adds another product, the function is run, "product1" would return `!= nil`, so the function would then increment and try "product2", which `= nil`, then the integer value (in this case, 2) is assigned to `valueIncrement` and then concatenated to the "products" name, resulting in the product being posted to the database under the field name - "product2"

[Database Structure Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EZ4K.png)

I am using the following code to achieve this.

```
func incrementNumber() {
    db.collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
    if data["product"] as? String == nil {
                                (products) = ["product1"]
                                        return
                                    } else {
                                      try (products)+=1
                                        
                                        if (products) != nil {
                                            let valueIncrement = products.product as! String
                                        }
                                    

                            let productDict =
                                 (productname,producturl,pricefield,proddesc,timeleft)

                             let combinedString = "\(productDict)"

                             document.reference.updateData([
                               "product \(valueIncrement)":(combinedString)

                             ])
                        }
                    }
                }
```

However I am getting the following error for curly brace (leaving me unable to test whether my function is working as intended) here - `getDocuments {`.

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(QuerySnapshot?, Error?) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(QuerySnapshot?, Error?) -> Void'

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what's going on with the code here. Where is `products` defined? It looks like you're trying to some operations on it that don't make much sense (at least to me). The compiler error your list is because you are using `try` outside of `do { }` - https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html . But, I'm not sure what you are trying to do on that line in the first place...

Comment: After reading your question again, I get a little more about what you're trying to do. It seems like a pretty questionable way to structure a database. If the database is of your own design, I *strongly* recommend abandoning this idea of storing the products this way and use an array instead.

Comment: You absolutely should not do what you're trying to do. Reading all records, then iterating one-by-one in order to find the "last" one, is both incredibly wasteful and could easily fail when multiple clients create records at the same time. Firebase has a built-in ID - use that.

Comment: Thanks for your answers both - if it was to follow the route of adding the data and concatenating it into an array, the data would be added like so: products:"iPhone" and then when I add another product it would update to products"iPhone,Samsung Galaxy", correct?